# Spring Boot not use profile from properties file in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I have service and test for it. When I run test, it not use profile property from `test.properties` file, but use with `@ActiveProfiles` annotation. Why Spring Boot not loads profile from properties file?

I see this from error that states Spring not found service bean. This happen even if I explicitly use service implementation class name in test:

```
@Autowired
SalaryIntervalsDBImpl salaryIntervalsDBImpl;
```

error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'healthjobs.service.SalaryIntervalsDBImplTest': Injection of autowired de
pendencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCre
ationException: Could not autowire field: healthjobs.service.SalaryIntervalsDBIm
pl healthjobs.service.SalaryIntervalsDBImplTest.salaryIntervalsDBImpl; nested ex
ception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No q
ualifying bean of type [healthjobs.service.SalaryIntervalsDBImpl] found for depe
ndency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotati
on.Autowired(required=true)}
```

All other properties are taken from `test.properties` file as they should.

Service annotated with:

```
@Service
@Profile("SIFromDB")
public class SalaryIntervalsDBImpl implements SalaryIntervals{
```

Test annotated with:

```
@ActiveProfiles("SIFromDB") //If I remove this test will crash
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(App.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class SalaryIntervalsDBImplTest {
```

test.properties file:

```
spring.profiles.active=SIFromDB
```

Comment: Why? test.properties file found and properties are read from it fine. Just one problem - profile.

Comment: hard to tell where the problem, just remove the @ActiveProfiles and debug into context, if profile is set.